# How to remove unwanted delimiter in json using python

Tags: json, python-3.x

```
jsonValue="{'Employee': ['{"userId":"rirani","jobTitleName":"Developer","firstName":"Romin","lastName":"Irani","preferredFullName":"Romin Irani","employeeCode":"E1","region":"CA","phoneNumber":"408-1234567","emailAddress":"romin.k.irani@gmail.com"}', '{"userId":"nirani","jobTitleName":"Developer","firstName":"Neil","lastName":"Irani","preferredFullName":"Neil Irani","employeeCode":"E2","region":"CA","phoneNumber":"408-1111111","emailAddress":"neilrirani@gmail.com"}', '{"userId":"thanks","jobTitleName":"Program Directory","firstName":"Tom","lastName":"Hanks","preferredFullName":"Tom Hanks","employeeCode":"E3","region":"CA","phoneNumber":"408-2222222","emailAddress":"tomhanks@gmail.com"}']}
"
with open("F://IDP Umesh//Data Transformation//test.json", 'w') as jsonFile:
    jsonFile.write(json.dumps(jsonValue))
```

### Out put from test.json

```
{"Employee": ["{\"userId\":\"rirani\",\"jobTitleName\":\"Developer\",\"firstName\":\"Romin\",\"lastName\":\"Irani\",\"preferredFullName\":\"Romin Irani\",\"employeeCode\":\"E1\",\"region\":\"CA\",\"phoneNumber\":\"408-1234567\",\"emailAddress\":\"romin.k.irani@gmail.com\"}", "{\"userId\":\"nirani\",\"jobTitleName\":\"Developer\",\"firstName\":\"Neil\",\"lastName\":\"Irani\",\"preferredFullName\":\"Neil Irani\",\"employeeCode\":\"E2\",\"region\":\"CA\",\"phoneNumber\":\"408-1111111\",\"emailAddress\":\"neilrirani@gmail.com\"}", "{\"userId\":\"thanks\",\"jobTitleName\":\"Program Directory\",\"firstName\":\"Tom\",\"lastName\":\"Hanks\",\"preferredFullName\":\"Tom Hanks\",\"employeeCode\":\"E3\",\"region\":\"CA\",\"phoneNumber\":\"408-2222222\",\"emailAddress\":\"tomhanks@gmail.com\"}"]}
```

How to remove '\' from the json content and make the valid json ?
Appreciate if anyone can help on this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
import json

jsonValue={'Employee': ['{"userId":"rirani","jobTitleName":"Developer","firstName":"Romin","lastName":"Irani","preferredFullName":"Romin Irani","employeeCode":"E1","region":"CA","phoneNumber":"408-1234567","emailAddress":"romin.k.irani@gmail.com"}', '{"userId":"nirani","jobTitleName":"Developer","firstName":"Neil","lastName":"Irani","preferredFullName":"Neil Irani","employeeCode":"E2","region":"CA","phoneNumber":"408-1111111","emailAddress":"neilrirani@gmail.com"}', '{"userId":"thanks","jobTitleName":"Program Directory","firstName":"Tom","lastName":"Hanks","preferredFullName":"Tom Hanks","employeeCode":"E3","region":"CA","phoneNumber":"408-2222222","emailAddress":"tomhanks@gmail.com"}']}
jsonValue['Employee'] =  [json.loads(i ) for i in jsonValue['Employee']]
print(jsonValue)
with open("test.json", 'w') as jsonFile:
    jsonFile.write(json.dumps(jsonValue))
```

The problem with your code is that you're dumping a string formatted as a json, dumps works when you need to convert a dict to a json formatted string.